# Debian 8.5 fresh installation failed with “tasksel: apt-get failed (100)” error

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I installed Debian 8.5 and the installation process went great, but after installation I brick the OS, so I tried again **fresh install**.

Since then the installation failed every time. I see two errors about failed to fetch some packages (from security.debian.org) with hash sum mismatch error. The packages are libreoffice-common_4.3.3 and gimp-data_2.8.14. Than I get the error "tasksel: apt-get failed (100)".

I tried different mirrors. I did memory test and disk check. Tried using other USB device, and re-download installation image. Searched for solution without any results.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: I saw here other questions about Linux installations, so I think it's appropriate to ask it here.